Pandas 2.0.3? Problems keeping format when file is saved in .json or .csv format
Here is some random code.
# create df
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1':['1_0','1_0','1_0','1_0','1_0'],
                   'var2':['X','y','a','a','a']})
df2.to_json('df2.json')

# import df
df2 = pd.read_json('df2.json')
df2

This is the expected output:
    var1    var2
0   1_0      X
1   1_0      y
2   1_0      a
3   1_0      a
4   1_0      a

However it generates:
    var1    var2
0   10      X
1   10      y
2   10      a
3   10      a
4   10      a

If I modify an entry inside ['var1'] to a string, then the code it generates when df is imported is correct.
Here is an example to illustrate it. I replaced one of the entries with 'hello'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1':['1_0','hello','1_0','1_0','1_0'],
                   'var2':['X','y','a','a','a']})
df2.to_json('df2.json')

# import df
df2 = pd.read_json('df2.json')
df2

Generates this
    var1    var2
0   1_0     X
1   hello   y
2   1_0     a
3   1_0     a
4   1_0     a

Same problem is observed if file is saved in csv format and then imported.
Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Maybe related https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17869

I think that is probably it and the workaround is spelled out there, I think. Use dtypes=False? Then maybe you don't need to insert a string. That is classic dtypes influence.

This is due to the fact that underscores are valid separators in python (often used as thousand separator: 1_000 is 1000). You could force the dtype upon import (or use dtype=False):
df2 = pd.read_json('df2.json', dtype='str')

If you want to keep dtype detection for the other columns:
df2 = pd.read_json('df2.json', dtype={'var1': 'str'})

Output:
  var1 var2
0  1_0    X
1  1_0    y
2  1_0    a
3  1_0    a
4  1_0    a

When you have a string in the json, there is no ambiguity that the values are not numbers and the conversion is not done.
